# How does autoconnect of wallet work?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, wallet

Does the solana wallet adapter autoconnect require the wallet to have already have been previously connected or will it automatically detect and connect a compatible wallet?

Answer (score 1):

< WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect >
... ...
< /WalletProvider >

it requires the wallet to have already been previously connected in my experiences